# Merging Multiple Stylesheets

Tags: javascript, css

i have been tasked with changing a bit of css for a site that i did not build and is quite old. Long story short - building the site from scratch is not an option.  There are two CSS stylesheets associated with the site.  I have tried combining them with no luck.  The first stylesheet is declared in the  head section of the document as normal.  The second seems to be pulled from the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function P7_StyleLoader(tS) { //v1.3 by PVII
var tH = '',
    tDoc = '',
    tA = '<LIN' + 'K REL="stylesheet" HREF=',
    tB = ' TYPE="text/css">';
if (document.getElementsByTagName) {
    var bb = document.getElementsByTagName("LINK");
    if (bb) {
        for (var k = 0; k < bb.length; k++) {
            if (bb[k].rel.toLowerCase() == "stylesheet") {
                var h = bb[k].href,
                    x = h.lastIndexOf("/");
                if (x > 0) {
                    tH = h.substring(0, x + 1);
                }
                bb[k].disabled = true;
                tDoc = tA + '"' + tH + tS + '"' + tB;
                document.write(tDoc);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
P7_StyleLoader('STYLE-SHEET-2.css');
//-->
</script>
```

if i merge them and drop one of these stylesheets from the html, the site pretty much breaks in terms of layout.  Could someone tell me if the above code is doing anything else besides just pulling "STYLE-SHEET-2.css"?  My thinking is that i'd like to use either the above code and put the other styles into it or vice-versa?  Am i missing something here?

thanks!

Comment: oh boy, that certainly is a convoluted way to pull in a stylesheet.  :-/

Comment: I reformatted here: http://jsfiddle.net/D52jJ/ Hope this helps!

Comment: Who *writes* this stuff? Seriously?

Comment: somebody took a lot of time to make this page very frustrating/non-expandable for any future developer.  I suggest highlighting this entire script block and pressing Delete.

Comment: @Patrick I agree! But then do include the stylesheet that is replaced

Comment: @mplungjan Probably not. The original designer probably had multiple sheets, and was completely lost when updating style-sheet-2.css and his/her changes were not displayed correctly. (probably because the same classes/styles were used in other sheets.) So instead of doing things correctly they just created a "forced override"

Comment: Yes but after running the above code, all modern browsers should only execute STYLE-SHEET-2.css

Comment: exactly... so if I was the OP, I wouldnt import any other css files until I had a handle on style-sheet-2.css.  I would remove the javascript, and import only style-sheet-2.css to start... then just expand from there... but it doesnt sound like the OP has very much flexibility... I would HOPE that he/she would atleast be able to do it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeuk. That is some nasty javascript.

What it's doing is roughly this: It scans through any `<link>` elements in the document already and disables them. It loads the stylesheet specified in the function call instead.

In addition, it works out what the directory path was in the original CSS include, and appends that to the front of the stylesheet it's loading, so that it is loaded from the same path as the original would have been.

The code is (slightly) obfuscated as well, presumably to prevent automated scripts from detecting what they're doing.

The question is why would anyone actually go to all that trouble?

I can't think of too many reasons why they may have done this. The only thing that makes sense would be to fool spam bots into loading the wrong styles or something similar to that. Make the page look different to a bot to how a human would see it. Possibly trying to fool search engine bots too, but that would be considered a very bad move - if Google catches on to that you'd get black-listed.

Comment: so if it's totally disabling the other stylesheet, why does it change how the page displays if i remove the reference in the head to "STYLE-SHEET-1.css"?  So odd.  It's like the page is referencing code in the stylesheet that's supposed to be disabled...

Comment: @lordryan: it is still referencing the first stylesheet - the script only *replaces* the existing stylesheets; if you don't have an existing stylesheet, then it doesn't have anything to replace, so it won't do anything. Really really nasty code. My advice is to ditch the Javascript bit entirely, and just load STYLE-SHEET-2.css in a normal <link> element.

Answer (score 3):

the code REPLACES the current stylesheets by disabling other stylesheets

It seems to be code designed to remove Netscape 4 specific stylesheets since NS4 does not understand the disabled stylesheet :)

Here is a 2002 discussion about this obviously even older code
http://www.webxpertz.net/forums/showthread.php?t=20718

Comment: wow. good catch. If that's what it is, then this is some seriously old code.

Answer (score 2):

The javascript fragment is disabling all stylesheet link statements, and importing only style-sheet-2.css.

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually, what it does is inserting a new -attribute for a stylesheet. You should view the DOM-document with firebug to view the exact generated link with style-sheet-2.css.

My guess is that it loads the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="STYLE-SHEET-2.css" type="text/css" />
```

It's also possible (re-read your code..) that it's stripping all other CSS and replace the src with this one. Very weird..